# Alt-Tab window switcher that responds to mouse clicks in MATE?

Tags: mate, application-switcher

The Alt-Tab window switcher is pretty great but there is one issue with it. When you click on a window while Alt-Tab is pressed, it doesn't switch to the window. It just closes the window switcher. So if you have 30 windows open but in order to see the window you want... you have to tab, tab, tab... until you get to it instead of just clicking it.

Is there some way to configure Ubuntu MATE so that when you click on a window in the window switcher, it will switch to that window?

I've heard from others that GNOME has this ability to click on the windows in the application switcher. So is there a way to use GNOME's application switcher in MATE?

I am using Ubuntu MATE 16.x and Ubuntu MATE 17.x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating my answer because this will now be possible. This has been added in this PR: https://github.com/mate-desktop/marco/pull/499

Will be available starting mate desktop v1.23.1

Not yet released as of today.

Comment: +1 for your effort. Following the links on GitHub and finally [the bug report on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mate/+bug/1739242), the first and only comment so far noted: "This is fixed in Ubuntu MATE 18.04." but mate-desktop 1.23.1 in [the Ubuntu Package Search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=mate-desktop&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=all&section=all) is not found yet.